# How does the d option for the ls command exactly work?

Tags: directory, ls, command

Having the following simple structure:

```
project
 main
  aaa
  aaa 
 test
  ddd
  ddd 
 pom.xml  <--- unique regular file
```

If the current directory is `project` and if is executed the `ls` command appears

```
main  pom.xml  test
```

Until here all is OK. Now, according with `man ls` about the `d` option exists:

```
   -d, --directory

          list directories themselves, not their contents
```

Thus when is executed the `ls -d` command appears:

```
.
```

Why? To be honest I expected only the directories and not regular files. Such as

```
main test
```

**Question**

- How does the `d` option for the `ls` command exactly work?

*Extra question*:

- What does *not their contents* exactly mean? Is it about of the internal content of each directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when you `ls` a directory then the contents of the directory are shown.

e.g. in your example:

```
$ ls project
main  test
$ ls project/main
aaa  aab
$ ls project/test
dda  ddb
```

If you use the `-d` flag then the directory itself is listed

```
$ ls -d project
project
```

This sounds boring until you look at things like wildcards:

```
$ ls project/*
project/main:
aaa  aab

project/test:
dda  ddb
```

We can see that each directory matched we get a list of the files in those directories.

But with `-d` we just get the directory names themselves and not the files inside the directories.

```
$ ls -d project/*
project/main  project/test
```

Comment: Just being curious, if `ls -d` is the same as `ls -d .` - so why the dot is not interpreted as the _current directory_ as relative path and is not shown the `main` and `test` directories?

Comment: `ls -d .` would display the `.` directory and not the _contents_ of the `.` directory;  You can see this if you combine with `l` flag; eg `ls -ld .` will show permissions and inode and stuff for the directory itself.

Comment: Thank You. Now is more clear that point, if you consider necessary consider to add it to your answer.

Comment: Just in case, at Ubuntu Desktop 22.04, the `ls -d project/*` command returns `project/main  project/pom.xml  project/test`. Therefore consider to fix that part and explain why appears the `pom.xml` file

Answer (score 5):

> How does the d option for the ls command exactly work?

`ls -d` is about not traversing directories further. `ls` with no argument is equivalent to `ls .`, which is why you only see `.` as output. As an example of how it can be used:

```
$ mkdir -p {foo,bar,baz}/dir
$ ls *
bar:
dir

baz:
dir

foo:
dir
$ ls -d *
bar  baz  foo
```

This can be particularly useful if you want to look at some of the directory metadata, for example, with `ls -ld`.

Comment: Just being curious, if `ls -d` is the same as `ls -d .` - so why the dot is not interpreted as the _current directory_ as relative path and is not shown the `main` and `test` directories?

Comment: @ManuelJordan Could you please clarify? I'm not sure I understand the question. `.` is a directory, so it follows the same rules as if you used the absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking a *very* broad question. 
But the short answer to your puzzlement is:
the default *argument* for `ls` (when none is specified) is **`.`**. 
When you run `ls` with no options, you get ***the contents of `.`**.* 
When you run `ls -d`, you get **`.`**.

Comment: Just being curious, if `ls -d` is the same as `ls -d .` - so why the dot is not interpreted as the _current directory_ as relative path and is not shown the `main` and `test` directories?

Comment: What do you mean? The dot ***is** interpreted* as the current directory.

Comment: But if `pwd` returns the current `project` location why either `ls -d` or `ls -d .` does not return the `main` and `test` as content? Why appears again the `.`? I am assuming it is related about `.` and `..` that exists in each directory - Am I correct?

Comment: It's right there in your question: `-d` tells `ls` to list directories themselves, not their contents.  This has nothing to do with `..`. When you say “`ls -d`” or “`ls -d .`”, you're saying “tell me about **`.`**, not its content.”  You may gain a better understanding of what `-d` does if you try “`ls -l`”, “`ls -la`” and “`ls -ld`”.